# How can I record the phone screen from the command prompt?

Tags: adb, screencast

I have been trying to record my phone screen (Nexus 5) through command prompt.  I have also downloaded the SDK. For some unknown reason I am unable to open or play the file saved using this script:

```
$adb shell /sdcard/video.mp4
```

Comment: What you call a "script" here actually is an ADB command that cannot work: `adb shell` just invokes a shell, without further parameters an interactive one. All you pass to it should be run on the device. But you didn't pass a command, but just a file name. So what shall be achieved here? Copying the file to your computer to play it there, or have the video played on the device?

Comment: Thank you Izzy, I always thought that the screen was getting recorded. Is it possible that you give me more insight on how do I record a screen? i tried apps like src screen recorders, but they also gave me an .mp4 file that could not play anywhere.

Comment: Where (and how) did you try to play the resulting file? Maybe there's something wrong on that end. For the recording part, you might wish to check our [other screencast questions](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/screencast) ("screencast" is the keyword for this, as is "screenshot" for the "still picture"). I've just fixed the tags on your question this way, too.

Comment: Thank you for the corrections. I used another app called "screencast", gave me a file that ran all black. Thanks for the link let me see if I can work with this help.

Answer (score 0):

You can exec this command from the pc

```
$ adb shell screenrecord /sdcard/video.mp4
```

Need Android 4.4 (which you should have).

DevBytes: Android 4.4 - Recording App Videos: http://youtu.be/ETzRxxOK_bs

Comment: Why does my recording never play?
 I have used the same adb commands to get a screen video.
 I get an mp4 file too. But it never plays in any player.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct command to record? In your original Q you said your using the command $adb shell /sdcard/video.mp4 but you need to add in the word 'screenrecord' after the word shell.

Comment: Yes I did, I did everything religiously!
Even when I try and play it on windows media player it gives me the following message, "Windows Media Player cannot play the file. The Player might not support the file type or might not support the codec that was used to compress the file."

Comment: Do I need SDK for all of this??

Comment: Possibly. Though if your using ABD haven't you already got it? I just tried it on my HTC One and Nexus 4 and both work fine.

Comment: I have the SDK too, ain't working yet!

Comment: What size is the file that it creates?

Comment: I made one for 2344 KB.

Comment: Have you tried playing it in another media player, such as [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-windows.html)? I had some issues when trying to record directly from the device where it would create a 3.3kb file and not play, however running the command from Windows works fine for me.